# copy script works on local server not when done remote

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run a script on several remote servers I'm getting access denied but when I RDP into the server and run that same script it works.

```
Enter-PSSession server
Copy-Item -path C:\Users\my.admin\*.html -Destination \\company\citrix\Documentation\Citrix\Inventory
```

Comment: You can't use `Enter-PSSession` in a script. You would have to use `$sess = New-PSSession -ComputerName pc1` and `Invoke-Command -Session $sess`. Also: post the error. An exception/error record says more than just that one line. This error might come from WSMan (can't connect to computer), but it could also come from inside the Remote sesion (copy failed).... It's probably double-hop issue, but you haven't provided enough info for me to be 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're experiencing the classic "double hop" issue.  You can resolve this with CredSSP delegation.  See the following link for an example of this:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/04/04/enabling-multihop-remoting/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a PSSession to copy a file. PSSessions only make it more complicated since you need to configure PSRemoting, firewall-rules, CredSSP or kerberos delegation (to get past the double-hop issue) etc. I would copy directly:

```
Copy-Item -path "\\server\c$\Users\my.admin\*.html" -Destination "\\company\citrix\Documentation\Citrix\Inventory"
```